# Build folder and makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

The question comes from my puzzlement when compiling a makefile for Deep Learning framework Caffe on Ubuntu, but it relates, I believe, to a more general phenomenon of the nature of compiling a C++ makefile.

After "make all", the resulting files from the compilation were put in a hidden folder: .build_release, not in the respective folders where the cpp files are.

Then when I tried to run the following lines:

```
./data/mnist/get_mnist.sh
./examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh
```

I was getting an error that the system does not find the file:

```
./create_mnist.sh: 16: ./create_mnist.sh:     build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.bin: not found
```

But the file actually existed in the .build_release folder.
What happened and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a "make install"?

Comment: There should be a README or INSTALL file or something similar describing the steps required for the installation. The usual procedure is something like `./configure`,  `make`, and `sudo make install`. Sometimes the first step is to run `./bootstrap`. It depends on the software package.

Comment: I solved the problem through just copying the files that appeared in the build_release folder.

Comment: I have the same issue, where did you find the `.build_release` directory?

Comment: This hidden file should be in the caffe directory, same where build is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with `make`, you simply need to follow the instructions carefully. The `BUILD_DIR` is specified by `Makefile.config`. By default this folder is named `build`. Once you followed the compilation instructions:

```
cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
# Adjust Makefile.config (for example, if using Anaconda Python)
make all
make test
make runtest
```

Navigate to `build`:

```
cd build
./data/mnist/get_mnist.sh
./examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh
```